# Convert a single hex character to its byte value in java

Tags: java, hex

I have a single hexadecimal character, say

```
char c = 'A';
```

What's the proper way of converting that to its integer value

```
int value =??; 
assert(a == 10);
```

Doesn't matter really for now if **a** is an int or a byte.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

i don't see why you should have to convert to string... in fact this is what parseInt uses:

[public static int digit(char ch, int radix)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,%20int))

```
int hv = Character.digit(c,16);
if(hv<0)
    //do something else because it's not hex then.
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int value;
try {
    value = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c), 16);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a hex char");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Found it myself though.

```
int i = Character.digit('A',16);
```

Answer (score 1):

(byte)Integer.parseInt("a", 16)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Commons Codec and in particular the Hex class.

http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html

You should be able to convert a hex char array or string to an int value using the toDigit() method:

```
protected static int toDigit(char ch, int index)
```

You'll need to catch DecoderException though.

```
try {
    int i = Hex.toDigit('C');
} catch (DecoderException de) {
    log.debug("Decoder exception ", de);
}
```

There's also methods there to convert a char[] or String to the corresponding byte array as well.